# Gain matrices of numerical schemes

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, runge-kutta-methods

**Introduction**

Say I have a linear multiple degree of freedom system, as below:
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{dx}{dt}=ax+by
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{dy}{dt}=dx+ey
\end{equation*}
This can also be written as $\frac{dr}{dt}=Ar$ with $A$ given by
\begin{equation*}
    A=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b \\
        c & d \\
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
Matrix $A$ can be used to write the numerical schemes (Euler, Heun and Runge-Kutta) using gain matrices.

For Euler is this
\begin{equation*}
    r_{n+1}=r_{n}+\frac{dr}{dt}\Delta t=r_{n}+Ar_{n}\Delta t
\end{equation*}
and rewriting gives
\begin{equation*}
    r_{n+1}=\left(I+A\Delta t\right)r_{n}.
\end{equation*}
Now we can multiply old vector $r_{n}$ with $G=(I+A\Delta t)$ to get the new vector $r_{n+1}$.

In a similar way, the gain matrices $(G)$ can be determined for the Heun and Runge-Kutta schemes.

For the Heun scheme follows
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        r_{n+1}&=r_{n}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{dr}{dt}\rvert_{(r_{n},t_{n})}+\frac{dr}{dt}\rvert_{(r_{p},t_{n+1})}\right)\Delta t \\
        &=r_{n}+\frac{1}{2}\left(Ar_{n}+Ar_{p}\right) \\
        &=r_{n}+\frac{1}{2}Ar_{n}\Delta t+\frac{1}{2}Ar_{p}\Delta t \\
        &=\left(I+\frac{1}{2}A\Delta t\right)r_{n}+\left(\frac{1}{2}A\Delta t\right)r_{p} \\
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}

**Question**

Runge Kutta is defined as
\begin{equation*}
r_{n+1}=r_{n}+\frac{1}{6}(k_{1}+2k_{2}+2k_{3}+k_{4})\Delta t
\end{equation*}
with
\begin{align*}
    k_{1}&=f\left(r_{n},t_{n}\right) \\
    k_{2}&=f\left(r_{n}+\frac{1}{2}k_{1}\Delta t,t_{n}+\frac{1}{2}\Delta t\right) \\
    k_{3}&=f\left(r_{n}+\frac{1}{2}k_{2}\Delta t,t_{n}+\frac{1}{2}\Delta t\right) \\
    k_{4}&=f\left(r_{n}+k_{3}\Delta t,t_{n}+\Delta t\right)
\end{align*}

For the Runge-Kutta scheme I can't figure out how to get gain matrices. Somebody who knows how to do this?

Comment: You know that you almost never need to use `\newline` in LaTeX if you use empty lines to separate paragraphs? Apart from that, mathjax here only renders inside math environments.

Comment: I always used MiKTeX and with that one I never even used \newline. Since today I started using Sharelatex and with that one it made new paragraphs if I had an empty line, so the text moved a bit to the right and I didn't want that to happen. So I used \newline to prevent it from making a new paragraph as a temporarily solution. :)

Comment: The paragraph indentation/separation style is language dependent, look that you load (and activate if more than one) the correct language with `babel`. Always specify the text language explicitly as the installations might have different default languages. Also look into the package `parskip`, and what using it could have for other consequences. Read the `l2tabu` document on easy-to-avoid errors or anti-patterns.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the paragraph thing is really not an issue. Normally for my reports it is fine, but for this little university assignment it is of least importance and I simply used \setlength{\parindent}{0cm}.

Comment: As I said, read the l2tabu doc, it is not that long and contains hints on how to do this correctly by also adjusting the `parskip` length (with elasticity additions). Using `\usepackage{parskip}` does all that automatically, with possible side effects in the spacing between theorem environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just insert the $f$ of the homogeneous linear equation,
\begin{alignat}{3}
k_1&=f(y)&&&&=Ay
\\
k_2&=f(y+0.5Δt·k_1)&&=A(y+0.5Δt·k_1))&&=Ay+0.5Δt·A^2y
\\
k_3&=f(y+0.5Δt·k_3)&&=A(y+0.5Δt·k_3))&&=Ay+0.5Δt·A^2y+0.25Δt^2·A^3y
\\
k_4&=f(y+Δt·k_4)&&=A(y+Δt·k_4)&&=Ay+Δt·A^2y+0.5Δt^2·A^3y+0.25Δt^3·A^4y
\\\hline
&k_1+2k_2+2k_3+k_4&&&&=6Ay+3Δt·A^2y+Δt^2·A^3y+0.25Δt^3·A^4y
\end{alignat}
which ends up giving the exact 4th order Taylor polynomial for $e^{Δt⋅A}y$ in the RK4 step.