# Is there a generalized formula for solving systems of ODEs using 4th order Runge-Kutta?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

As far as I know, we numerically solve any system by reducing it to ODEs and somehow we manage to wire the new system into the RK algorithm. I have seen solutions where there are formulas to use the basic algorithm on a $2$- or $3$-dimensional problem, but so far I don't really understand how we do it.

I mean here basic differential equations so no partial differential equations, no delay, etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Linear? Nonlinear? Constant parameters?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo : I think it is less about some concrete type and more on the step from where most tutorials on numerical method for ODE end (with RK4 for Volterra-Lotka and Lorenz) towards the implementation of more generally useful solvers.

Comment: Indeed, my goal is to have a tool that somehow can solve higher order differential equations

Comment: @LutzLehmann Since you know a lot more about ODEs than I do, if I may ask, if I have $\dot x = A x$ and use the 4th order truncated Taylor expansion of $e^{h A}$, I have a state-transition matrix that produces a state sequence that is "equivalent" to the one produced by RK4, right?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo : [Yes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2177590/gain-matrices-of-numerical-schemes). That pattern is true for all explicit methods where $s=p$, stage number equal to order, that is, all the usual low-order methods. From 5th order on there will be additional terms after the truncated power series.

Comment: 4th order RK is the general formula for solving ODEs. What is your question?

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I think I can manage to reduce a higher order problem to ODEs. Then my problem is the following : I don't see generally how can I transform the problem to a $$ x' = F(t,x(t)) $$ vector / matrix definition for which I am able to use RK.

My goal is to make a script where I insert my higher order problem then it calculates a numerical solution.

Comment: @SzabBence see my answer then.

Comment: @SzabBence - what language/environment are you using. Chances are someone has already done this before.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking for a general algorithm to implement an Rk4 scheme with some programming language. The implementation needs the following definitions:

1. An array/vector holding the state variables (all the DOF of the system).

   $$ \boldsymbol{Y} = \pmatrix{y_1 \\ y_2 \\ \vdots \\ y_n} $$

   Note that for a dynamical system half the state variables are going to represent positions and half are going to represent velocities (or momentum). In the example of $N$ connected spring-masses you have

   $$ \boldsymbol{Y} = \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{X} \\\boldsymbol{\dot X} \end{bmatrix} = \pmatrix{x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_N \\ \hline \dot{x}_1 \\ \vdots \\ \dot{x}_N} $$ with $n=2 N$ state variables.
2. A model of the ODE in terms of the rate of change of the state variable as a vector function of time and the current state

   $$ \boldsymbol{\dot Y} = \mathbf{f}(\,t,\;\boldsymbol{Y}) $$

   In the example of $N$ connected spring-masses the model is something like

   $$ \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{X} \\\boldsymbol{\dot X} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ \mathbf{M}^{-1} \boldsymbol{F(t)} \end{bmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix}0 & \mathbf{1} \\ -\mathbf{M}^{-1} \mathbf{K} & -\mathbf{M}^{-1} \mathbf{C} \end{vmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{X} \\\boldsymbol{\dot X} \end{bmatrix}$$

   where $\mathbf{M}$ is the mass matrix, $\mathbf{K}$ is the stiffness matrix, $\mathbf{C}$ is the damping matrix and $\boldsymbol{F(t)}$ is the forcing vector.
3. The initial conditions for the ODE, given a starting state vector $\boldsymbol{Y}_0$ and time $t_0=0$.
4. To run the simulation until time $t_{\rm end}$ using $r$ steps, each tiome step is $h = t_{\rm end}/r$. The RK4 algorithm would look like this

   ```
   t = 0
   Y = Y_0
   ! store step [t,Y]
   do while(t < t_end)
       K_0 = f(t, Y)
       Y_1 = Y + h/2*K_0
       K_1 = f(t+h/2, Y_1)
       Y_2 = Y + h/2*K_1
       K_2 = f(t+h/2, Y_2)
       Y_3 = Y + h*K_2
       K_3 = f(t+h, Y_3)
       t = t + h
       Y = Y + h/6*(K_0 + 2*K_1 + 2*K_2 + K_3)
       ! store step [t,Y]
   end do
   ```

   I hope you can read the above Fortran code as the math operations are the easiest to understand IMHO. Assumes basic linear algebra is available where scalar-vector product $\lambda Y$ is defined, and vector-vector addition $Y_1 + Y_2$ is also defined.

Comment: Read http://geo.mff.cuni.cz/~vackar/lectures/NOFY056/f16-1-ODEs-RK.pdf for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you mean systems of differential equations of the ordinary type, no partial derivatives, no delay, function and derivative all evaluated at the same state vector.

These get indeed transformed into an explicit system of ODE of order 1
$$
\vec x'(t)=\vec F(t,\vec x(t)).
$$
These you can now insert into the Runge-Kutta method of your choice. For the step from demonstrative but simple methods to serious applications the educational methods used are the stereotypical order 4 Heun-Kutta RK4 method with fixed step-size on the simple side and the embedded order 4(5) Fehlberg method with step-size control on the serious side.

<sub>(RKF45 is dated, the same can be said for the popular DoPri45. There are also simple methods like Fehlberg23 that demonstrate the variable-step principle with a simple but non-trivial step computation.)</sub>

While as an intermediate step a component-wise implementation of the method step is often seen, the most clean and reusable implementation never leaves the vector formulation using vector or array data types. In some programming languages (with vector types with overloaded arithmetic operations) the same method step implementation can be used for the scalar and the vector case. The surrounding time loop has to make a distinction if the trajectory data is collected in a list.

Comment: I have edited the question, thank you for the remarks. I meant ordinary types as you mentioned. Thank you for the formula-explanation! I need to digest it, but I see that the basic idea is to transform it to a higher dimensional function, after that the same  formula applies. I think i need to research about how to write a higher dimensional problem to ODEs so I can find a way to automatise it

Comment: It is useful to study the interfaces of commonly used solver packages. The method choice of Matlab is rather outdated, but the interface design is one of the more simple ones. Closely related is `solve_ivp` of python-scipy. Compare that to the boiler-plate code required for the GSL (Gnu scientific library) solvers or boost::odeint (in theory that makes systematic extensions easier, practically this has not happened much).

Comment: Could you please give a brief explanation about these topics that you mentioned above? I am not an expert but I wish to have a better understanding in it